# Query to calculate the amount of seat booked and left in a screen

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a query to check how many seats have been filled and how many seats are left in a row for a movie in a screen but after hours of trying I'm still unable to get my head around it, I have tried many queries altering the where clause even sub queries, every time I get some error :(

The query I am using this as follows:

```
select 
    10 as [total seats in a row],
    perName as [movie name],
    seatRow as [seat row],
    (filledSeats - 10) as [seats left in a row]
    count(s.seatNo) filledSeats  
FROM 
     seats as s inner join 
     tickets as t on s.seatNo = t.seatNo inner join 
     performances as p on t.perID = p.perID 
 where 
     screenNo = '2' AND 
     perName = '50 shades of Grey'
 group by 
     perName
```

But even this one is giving me error

the sample data is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE seats (
seatNo int IDENTITY (1,1) not null,
screenNo int,
screen varchar (20),
seatType Varchar (10),
seatRow varchar (5),
PRIMARY KEY (seatNo),
FOREIGN KEY (screenNo) REFERENCES screens
);
insert into seats values ('1','3', 'Normal', 'A');
insert into seats values ('1','3', 'Normal', 'B');
insert into seats values ('1','3', 'VIP', 'D');
insert into seats values ('1','1', 'Normal', 'F');
insert into seats values ('1','3', 'VIP', 'E');
insert into seats values ('1','2', 'VIP', 'C');
insert into seats values ('1','1', 'VIP', 'C');
insert into seats values ('2','2', 'Normal', 'D');
insert into seats values ('2','1', 'VIP', 'F');
insert into seats values ('2','2', 'Normal', 'B');
insert into seats values ('2','1', 'Normal', 'B');
insert into seats values ('2','2', 'VIP', 'B');
insert into seats values ('2','2',  'Normal', 'A');
insert into seats values ('3','2', 'VIP', 'B');
insert into seats values ('2','1', 'Normal', 'C');
insert into seats values ('3','3', 'Normal', 'E');
insert into seats values ('3','2', 'VIP', 'C');
insert into seats values ('3','3', 'VIP', 'A');
insert into seats values ('3','1', 'VIP', 'E');
insert into seats values ('3','1', 'Normal', 'D');   

CREATE TABLE performances( 
perID int IDENTITY (1,1)NOT NULL,  
perName varchar (50),
perTime Time,
perDate Date, 
perType varchar (20),
duration varchar (10),
screenNo int,
rating varchar (10),
location varchar (10),
PRIMARY KEY (perID),   
);
insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '12:00', '2015-03-08',     'Movie', '2hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '15:00', '2015-02-20', 'Movie', '2hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '18:00', '2015-02-26', 'Movie', '2hrs', '3', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '21:00', '2015-03-28', 'Movie', '2hrs', '2', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Paddington', '12:00', '2015-03-26', 'Movie', '2:30hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Paddington', '15:00', '2015-03-03', 'Movie', '2:30hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Paddington', '18:00', '2015-02-02', 'Movie', '2:3hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Paddington', '21:00', '2015-03-31', 'Movie', '2:30hrs', '1', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Shakespeare', '12:00', '2015-02-25', 'Movie', '3hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Shakespeare', '15:00', '2015-02-06', 'Movie', '3hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Shakespeare', '18:00', '2015-02-13', 'Movie', '3hrs', '3', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Shakespeare', '21:00', '2015-01-09', 'Movie', '3hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Jupiter Ascending', '12:00', '2015-01-11', 'Movie', '2:3hrs', '1', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Jupiter Ascending', '15:00', '2015-01-19', 'Movie', '2:30hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Jupiter Ascending', '18:00', '2015-02-06', 'Movie', '2:3hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('Jupiter Ascending', '21:00', '2015-01-02', 'Movie', '2:3hrs', '2', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '12:00', '2015-01-06', 'Movie', '2hrs', '1', '18', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '15:00', '2015-03-28', 'Movie', '2hrs', '3', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '18:00', '2015-02-09', 'Movie', '2hrs', '2', 'PG', 'Chelmsford');
insert into performances values ('50 Shades of Grey', '21:00', '2015-02-06', 'Movie', '2hrs', '2', '18', 'Chelmsford');


CREATE TABLE bookings( 
     bookingID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,  
     customerID int ,
     clerkID varchar (20) ,
     perID int,
     ticketBooked int, 
     bookingDate Date,   
     bookingTime time,
     bookingType varchar(20),
     totalCost decimal(5,2),
     PRIMARY KEY (bookingID),
     FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customers,
     FOREIGN Key (clerkID) REFERENCES clerks, 
    );  

insert into bookings values (16, 'clerk04', 1, 2, '2015-02-24', '12:00', 'Normal', '20');
insert into bookings values (2, 'clerk02', 20,3, '2015-02-25', '15:00', 'Advance', '34');
insert into bookings values (10, 'clerk04', 3,5, '2015-02-17', '18:00', 'Advance', '75');
insert into bookings values (5, 'clerk01', 19,2, '2015-01-24', '21:00', 'Advance', '30');
insert into bookings values (13, 'clerk01', 4,1, '2015-02-05', '12:00', 'Normal', '10');
insert into bookings values (20, 'clerk04', 5,1,'2015-01-26', '15:00', 'Normal', '12');
insert into bookings values (4, 'clerk03', 6, 3,'2015-02-09', '18:00', 'Advance', '30');
insert into bookings values (1, 'clerk03', 2, 1,'2015-01-03', '21:00', 'Advance', '15');
insert into bookings values (17, 'clerk04', 3, 1,'2015-02-09', '12:00', 'Normal', '12');
insert into bookings values (9, 'clerk02', 18,2,'2015-02-02', '15:00', 'Advance', '20');
insert into bookings values (11, 'clerk01', 6,3,'2015-02-10', '18:00', 'Advance', '45');
insert into bookings values (18, 'clerk01',1 ,1,'2015-02-06', '21:00', 'Normal', '12');
insert into bookings values (8, 'clerk05', 5,2,'2015-01-13', '12:00', 'Advance', '20');
insert into bookings values (6, 'clerk02', 7,2,'2015-02-05', '15:00', 'Advance', '20');
insert into bookings values (10, 'clerk03', 8,1,'2015-02-14', '18:00', 'Normal', '15');
insert into bookings values (14, 'clerk01', 9,2,'2015-01-19', '21:00', 'Normal', '20');
insert into bookings values (7, 'clerk05', 10, 3,'2015-01-29', '12:00', 'Advance','34');
insert into bookings values (3, 'clerk01', 12, 1,'2015-02-18', '15:00', 'Normal', '12');
insert into bookings values (13, 'clerk02', 15,3,'2015-01-08', '18:00', 'Normal', '45');
insert into bookings values (19, 'clerk03', 6, 2,'2015-01-27', '21:00', 'Normal', '30');

 CREATE Table tickets (
 ticketNo int  IDENTITY (1,1) Not Null,
 bookingID int,  
 perID int,
 seatNo int,
 ticketType varchar(10),
 ticketDate date, 
 ticketPrice decimal (4,2),
 screen int,
 perTime time,
 PRIMARY KEY (ticketNo),
 FOREIGN KEY (bookingID) REFERENCES bookings,
 FOREIGN KEY (perID) REFERENCES performances, 
 FOREIGN KEY (seatNo) REFERENCES seats,
 ); 
insert into tickets values (20, 1, 1,'Student', '2015-01-12', '10 ', '1', '15:00');
insert into tickets values (19, 7, 2,'VIP', '2015-01-11', '15', '2', '21:00');
insert into tickets values (18, 1, 3,'Adult', '2015-02-21', '12', '2', '15:00');
insert into tickets values (17, 19, 4,'Adult', '2015-03-25', '12', '1', '18:00');
```

Comment: Can you add schema and sample data for `tickets`, which your query refers to?

Comment: Hi bohemian 

Please check the post I have updated

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any schema (or data) for `tickets`, and `bookings` although not used in your query has its schema and data shown, so I can only guess at what you want.

That said, this is your query with (I believe) syntax problems corrected:

```
select 
  10 as [total seats in a row],
  perName as [movie name],
  seatRow as [seat row],
  count(s.seatNo) - 10 as [seats left in a row],
  count(s.seatNo) filledSeats
FROM seats as s
join tickets as t on s.seatNo = t.seatNo
join performances as p on t.perID = p.perID 
where screenNo = '2'
AND perName = '50 shades of Grey'
group by perName, seatRow
```

---

Regarding the error you report, you're getting that error because once you give a table an alias, the table is effectively renamed for the query to that alias - so you can not refer to the full table name.

Change `performances.perName` to `p.perName`.

Comment: If u see my query properly there is no performance.perName! That's the error I got i have used per Name or p.perName

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT
 s.seatType,
 COUNT(*) as [total seats in a row],
 perName as [movie name],
 seatRow as [seat row],
 COUNT(*) - SUM(CASE WHEN t.perID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [seats left in a row],
 SUM(CASE WHEN t.perID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) filledSeats
 FROM performances as p
    INNER JOIN seats as s
ON s.screenNo = p.screenNo
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT b.perid ,t.seatNo
        FROM bookings b
        INNER JOIN tickets as t 
        ON  t.bookingid = b.bookingid
    )T
 ON s.seatNo = t.seatNo
    AND T.perid = p.perid
 WHERE p.perid = 1
 GROUP BY perName, s.seatType,seatRow
```

You can look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bff5c/1)

I changed some of the input data as the related IDs were incorrect. The schema has redundant columns.

- your `seats` table has a reference to a `screen` table and also a `screen` column apart from the FK `screenNo`.
- `Tickets` has a FK to performance as well as booking (which in turn has a FK to performance). These columns look redundant as well (`ticketDate, screen and pertime`)
- `Location` in `performance` table looks to be an attribute of `screen` or another location specific table which should be referred by `screen`.

Comment: Thanks ughai for the reply but what is t.id in the case when statement, I don't have that in my tables columns

Comment: @xack its supposed to be the primary column of the table tickets. you can use t.seatNo or t.perId as well. See updated code.

Comment: Hi Ughai i just tested the query it is giving me the following error                               Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "seats.seatType" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "seats.seatType" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

Solving problems; step by step:

1. After `(filledSeats - 10) as [seats left in a row]` a `,` is missed.
2. `filledSeats` is not a valid field in your tables, So where is it from?
   If it is the next field it should be `count(s.seatNo)` again, because you can't use aliases in your current query
3. `screenNo` is not a valid field also in your query, because it needs a prefix that determines that it's coming from where like `s.screenNo` or `p.screenNo`.
4. when you have a field like `seatRow` after `select` without any aggregation function you should call it after `group by` too.

So below query will have no error; but needs some edits:

```
select 
    10 as [total seats in a row],
    perName as [movie name],
    seatRow as [seat row],
    (count(s.seatNo) - 10) as [seats left in a row],
    count(s.seatNo) as filledSeats  
FROM 
     seats as s inner join 
     tickets as t on s.seatNo = t.seatNo inner join 
     performances as p on t.perID = p.perID 
 where 
     p.screenNo = '2' AND 
     perName = '50 shades of Grey'
 group by 
     perName, seatRow
```

So if you use it your result is:

```
total seats in a row | movie name           | seat row | seats left in a row | filledSeats
---------------------+----------------------+----------+---------------------+------------
10                   | 50 Shades of Grey    | F        | -9                  | 1
```

And if you change `(count(s.seatNo) - 10)` to `(10 - count(s.seatNo))` you will have `9` instead of `-9`.